# INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT when on lower version than lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, dex

I always get this error when i try to run my app on lower than lollipop api's. [Click here to see error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYq2Z.png) 
**Run**

```
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/batstate.commutersalertbutton
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
Error while Installing APK
```

**LogCat**

```
 02-19 22:28:13.904 1937-1944/com.google.android.gms E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                      java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                          at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:111)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:149)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:259)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:223)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:106)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:46)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>(DexClassLoader.java:57)
                                                                          at com.google.android.chimera.container.DexOptUtils.optimizeModule(:com.google.android.gms:86)
                                                                          at bcs.run(:com.google.android.gms:1726)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


02-19 22:31:03.120 1706-1722/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.closeGuardOpen(:com.google.android.gms:383)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms:297)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.PreKitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms:318)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(:com.google.android.gms:217)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(:com.google.android.gms:507)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:197)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:943)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:761)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:669)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:653)
                                                                        at cyh.a(:com.google.android.gms:233)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:263)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:4235)
                                                                        at dmw.a(:com.google.android.gms:47)
                                                                        at dmq.a(:com.google.android.gms:55)
                                                                        at dmp.a(:com.google.android.gms:113)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms:3054)
                                                                        at mwx.run(:com.google.android.gms:179)
02-19 22:31:03.120 1706-1722/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
                                                                        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                        at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
                                                                        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:96)
                                                                        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:547)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:850)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
                                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:797)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(:com.google.android.gms:762)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:669)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(:com.google.android.gms:653)
                                                                        at cyh.a(:com.google.android.gms:233)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:263)
                                                                        at dmx.a(:com.google.android.gms:4235)
                                                                        at dmw.a(:com.google.android.gms:47)
                                                                        at dmq.a(:com.google.android.gms:55)
                                                                        at dmp.a(:com.google.android.gms:113)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms:3054)
                                                                        at mwx.run(:com.google.android.gms:179)
```

and when i tried to run my app again it displays this. [Click here to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D58zn.png). But when i try to run it on upper lollipop versions there's no problem. I tried cleaning the project.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the apk and then recompile it? Using Android Emulator or Device?

Comment: I can't uninstall it because it didn't install on the first place. And i tried to wipe data on the emulator.

Comment: Happens to me also. Its working on higher versions, for some reason doesn't work on 22. Same situation, emulator is new, clean, nothing installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your gradle.properties

```
android.enableD8=false
android.enableD8.desugaring= false
```